# Protractor custom drag and drop not working

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, selenium, protractor

I need to move element with mouse, but since native browser.action() is not working , I try to use following method to do so:

```
module.exports = function simulateDragDrop(sourceNode, destinationNode) {
console.log('simulatingDragDrop');
var EVENT_TYPES = {DRAG_END: 'dragend', DRAG_START: 'dragstart', DROP: 'drop'}

function createCustomEvent(type) {
    console.log('createCustomEvent');
    var event = new CustomEvent("CustomEvent")
    event.initCustomEvent(type, true, true, null)
    event.dataTransfer = {
        data: {}, setData: function (type, val) {
            this.data[type] = val
        }, getData: function (type) {
            return this.data[type]
        }
    }
    return event
}

function dispatchEvent(node, type, event) {
    if (node.dispatchEvent) {
        return node.dispatchEvent(event)
    }
    if (node.fireEvent) {
        return node.fireEvent("on" + type, event)
    }
}

var event = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START)
dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_START, event)
var dropEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DROP)
console.log(event.dataTransfer);
console.log(dropEvent.dataTransfer);
dropEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
dispatchEvent(destinationNode, EVENT_TYPES.DROP, dropEvent)
var dragEndEvent = createCustomEvent(EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END)
dragEndEvent.dataTransfer = event.dataTransfer
dispatchEvent(sourceNode, EVENT_TYPES.DRAG_END, dragEndEvent)
```

Then in test itself I have:

```
var dragAndDropFn = require('../../../services/native_js_drag_and_drop_helper');

let elementA = element(by.automationId('ElementA'));
let elementB = element(by.automationId('ElementB'));

browser.executeScript(dragAndDropFn, elementA.getWebElement(), elementB.getWebElement());
```

It does work on simple html5 test page, but when I use it in my application it does nothing:

My html is:

```
<div _ngcontent-kxy-11="" class="handle" draggable="true"     automationid="ElementA">
<i _ngcontent-kxy-11="" class="icon-draghandle"></i>
```

and same with ElementB. I do have to note that elements are found, and that is not the problem. Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? The HTML5 drag and drop can be tricky to simulate depending on how it is implemented in the page.